# React how to: replace only one component on click (dynamic UI)

Tags: html, reactjs

Using react.js I want to make a dynamic UI, I have something like this:

```
<div>
  <appbar component />
  <drawer (sidebar) comopnent /> <!-- <--has buttons -->
  <content component> <!-- <-- component to replace or re-render -->
  <footer component>
</div>
```

Then I try to use an state to save and change the "" like this:

```
 const [renderView, setRenderView] = useState("<Home />");

/* onclick call this function and pass referenced component ej: <reports /> */

function changeContent(view){ 
        setRenderView(view);

        return(
         <Suspense fallback={renderLoader()}>
            {view}
        </Suspense>
        );

    }
```

Now, how to replace the " content component " with the new one?.

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: If the props passed to "conent component" change, react will automatically render it again. For us to provide more details, we need a [mcve] that we can compile and run. Your current example is pseudocode that can't compile.

Comment: Not sure you want to pass components through state. Instead make the state be a useful value like a boolean or an id, then show/hide the component you want with simple expression based on the updated state. `{ showDrawer && <ComponentToShow /> }`. Wouldn't that work better?

Comment: i will make an example in short, using state to on/off components is not a bad idea, i will try to use with "lazyLoading", because i dont want to load all components at once, also im trying to figure the best practice to do that

Answer (score 0):

i made this bassed on suggestions, its working, but im not using class just functions

function Dashboard(props) {

```
/* lazy loading */
const renderLoader = () => <p>Loading...!?¡?</p>;

/* lazy components */
const Initial = () => (
  <Suspense fallback={renderLoader()}>
      <InitialComponent />
  </Suspense>
)
const Reports = () => (
    <Suspense fallback={renderLoader()}>
        <ReportsComponent />
    </Suspense>
)
const Cards = () => (
  <Suspense fallback={renderLoader()}>
      <CardsComponent />
  </Suspense>
)

/* set view state */
const [renderView, setRenderView] = useState(Initial());

function changeContent(view){
    setRenderView(view);

}

const test = (cosa) => {
  console.log(cosa);
}

/* style things*/
const classes = useStyles();
const fixedHeightPaper = clsx(classes.paper, classes.fixedHeight);

return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <UIappbar />
    <UIsidebar />
    <main className="contentWrapper">
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={8} lg={9}>
            <div>
                <Button onClick={() => changeContent(Reports())}>Reports view</Button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <Button onClick={() => changeContent(Cards())}>Cards view</Button>
            </div>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={8} lg={9}>
                <Paper className={fixedHeightPaper}>
                {renderView}
                </Paper>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </main>
    </div>
);
```

}

Now i need to call "changeContent()" that has the method to change {renderView} need to call it from a child  
dont know how to pass props without class format (im using functions only)

should i change to class with constructor format?